# JSON won't import

Tags: json, python-3.6, discord.py

I'm creating a Discord moderator bot, and I want to create a "custom prefix per server".

My problem is that I'm trying to import json library but it doesn't work. It returns an error.

I'm using the following code (test code)

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import json
import asyncio

with open("prefixes.json") as json_data:
    prefixes = json.load(json_data)
default_prefix = "!"

def prefix(bot, message):
    id = message.server.id
    return prefixes.get(id, default_prefix)

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix)

@bot.command(name="prefix", pass_context=True)
async def _prefix(ctx, new_prefix):
    # Do any validations you want to do
    prefixes[ctx.message.server.id] = new_prefix
    with open("prefixes.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f)


. . .
```

I get this error from the code above:

```
===== RESTART: C:\Users\Raphaël\Desktop\Python\Moderator Bot\coreTest.py =====
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Raphaël\Desktop\Python\Moderator Bot\coreTest.py", line 6, in <module>
    prefixes = json.load(json_data)
  File "C:\Users\Raphaël\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 299, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Raphaël\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Raphaël\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Raphaël\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 3 column 2 (char 30)
>>>
```

Comment: I prefilled the prefixes.json file with two discord servers' informations and prefix to use

Comment: What does `"prefixes.json"` look like? The error is complaining that it cannot be loaded, so likely the file is formatted properly as `json`

Comment: The error is in your `prefixes.json`.  It should look something like `{"1234": "$", "5678": "@"}`.  See https://json.org/

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of the problem, I forgot a comma.
Now it's working.